# How can I convert an image to grayscale via the command line?

Tags: linux, image, command-line, sips

How can I use `sips`, `imagemagic`, or another tool to convert an image to black and white (grayscale) via the command line?

Comment: Open built-in python: `from PIL import Image ; Image.open('a.png').convert('L').save('grey.png')`
for those who prefer staying away from software installing.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

If you have `imagemagick` installed,

```
convert source.jpg -colorspace Gray destination.jpg (true grayscale only)
convert source.jpg -monochrome destination.jpg (true black and white)
convert source.jpg -separate destination.jpg (separate into gray channels)
```

If you don't care about losing the original file: `mogrify -colorspace Gray file`.

Comment: None of these actually convert a `AxBx3` `RGB` image into a `AxBx1` single channel grayscale image though.

Answer (score 17):

use one of: `-monochrome` or `-colorspace gray` options for `imagemagick` (`convert`).