# Convert mp4 from color to black-and-white with linux terminal

Tags: terminal

I have an mp4 which I want to convert from color to black and white using the terminal.

How?

EDIT: My question is NOT a duplicate because I want to do this with an mp4 (video, not image).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an image to grayscale via the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708368/how-can-i-convert-an-image-to-grayscale-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

If you install [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (cross-platform video converter), you can do it with a one line command by filtering the saturation to 0.

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfile> -vf hue=s=0 -acodec copy <outputfile>
```

Comment: please consider adding a comment to your answer, which seems to do it, but without explanation, it's not really useful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overkill but GStreamer could probably achieve that. It's mainly for streaming media but you can use it to manipulate local files also.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

It can either be executed as a command taking your mp4 as argument along with a long series of other arguments directly from the terminal or the framework can be imported in a project. Takes some time to get the hang of it tho and it's probably an easier way.

Comment: Thanks I might try this. I will be doing my video editing on a Windows boot tho.